# Why Response.Redirect doesn't execute next line of code?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I have a regular Asp.Net 4.0 webforms website. When I do:

```
Response.Redirect("SomePage.aspx");
```

I'd expect that my next line of code would be executed. However, surprisingly the next line of code is never executed. Can anybody know when and why does that happen?

Comment: You're already redirecting the page away. Code in next line therefore will not be executed.

Comment: @Shivan: How? Shouldn't Response.Redirect should just set the location header in Response headers? Does it include a "return" keyword which would prevent the next line from executing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Response.Redirect` also accepts two parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). The second parameter which is a boolean denotes whether the execution of the current page should terminate.

So, calling `Response.Redirect("Page.aspx",false)` would execute the subsequent lines of code and will avoid `ThreadAbortException` being flooded in your log files.

**Update: To answer why the default behavior is to not execute**

When `Response.Redirect` is used the expectation is to send only the 302 header to the client. Hence by default, it flushes the response & aborts the current thread, so the subsequent action will not be performed.

Example, in the authorization / authentication module once we know that the user is not eligible to access the resource, we just do a redirection and rest of the event life cycle should not get executed for security reasons.

Answer (score 5):

Any response body content such as displayed HTML text or Response.Write text in the page indicated by the original URL is ignored. **In addition, code execution in the current page is terminated when the Redirect method is processed, so subsequent code in the page will also be ignored.**

source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score -1):

response.redirect is equal to return statement in function. so as any line you write after return will never be executed. Same is true for response.redirect(). The current page execution is terminated after response.redirect()